# UITabBarController - How to switch to tab of a particular type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` implemented by a custom class (eg `HomeTabBarController`) and in my storyboard I've attached to it 3 `ViewController` as it's child.

I know that I can use, in order to select a particular view controller, in my `UITabBarController`:

```
selectedIndex = 2
```

But I would like to make my project a bit more flexible, so I would like to select a child tab only knowing it's **type**, not it's position. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the StackOverflow [documentation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) I'm going to answer my own question.

Let's make an example, you have a `UITabBarController` with 3 childs:

- `HomeTabBarController`
- `CustomAViewController`
- `CustomBViewController`
- `CustomCViewController`

In your `HomeTabBarController` controller you can put a func as this:

```
func selectCustomATab()    {
    var tab = 0
    
    for v in viewControllers!   {
        for k in v.childViewControllers {
            if k is CustomAViewController  {
                tab = viewControllers!.indexOf(v)!
            }
        }
    }
    
    selectedIndex = tab
}
```

And that's all, you can repeat for every `ViewController` child as you like.

Then in any `ViewController` child you can do something like that in order to switch tab:

```
(self.tabBarController as! HomeTabBarController).selectCustomATab()
```

Completely ignoring what's the `CustomAViewController` position in the tab array.

Answer (score 0):

set you're tab bar index value

```
tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2
```

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the question, I know. But I would like to make the project more flexible. In the way I shown I can change the position of the `ViewController` childs in storyboard without caring of any change in the code.

Comment: var index: Int = self.tabBarController.viewControllers.indexOfObjectIdenticalTo(specificViewController)

Comment: Just tried but (at least with Swift 2.2) `viewControllers` doesn't have such method